# Have to click button twice for function to execute

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get a popup to disappear once I click the `Add Comment` button but I have to click it twice for it to work. When I click it the first time the two buttons disappear and reappear. Then when I click it the second time it disappears as it should and the function works as it should.

The back button works perfectly with the popup disappearing on the first click. I am assuming it has something to do with trying to do it within my commenting function but I can't figure it out.

HTML code:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popupComment" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-all">
    <form>
        <div style="padding:10px 20px;">
            <h3>Please add comment</h3>
            <label for="un" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Comment:</label>
            <input type="text" name="comment" id="comment" value="" placeholder="Comment" data-theme="a">
            <button onclick="goCommenting()" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Add Comment</button>
            <button onclick="document.getElementById('popupComment').style.display='none'; event.preventDefault();" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-b ui-btn-icon-left ui-icon-check">Back</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

JavaScript code:

```
function goCommenting(){

    //alert(document.getElementById("comment").value);
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var listener1 = map.addListener('click', function(e) {

                //var comment = document.getElementById("editNameBox").value;
                placeMarkerAndPanTo(e.latLng, map,comment);
            });


    function placeMarkerAndPanTo(latLng, map) {
        var commentMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            draggable:true
        });
        (function (commentMarker) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(commentMarker, "click", function (e) {
                //Wrap the content inside an HTML DIV in order to set height and width of InfoWindow.
                infoWindow.setContent("<div>'"+document.getElementById("comment").value+"'</div>");
                infoWindow.open(map, commentMarker);
            });
        })(commentMarker);

        //(function (commentMarker) {
            google.maps.event.addListener(
                commentMarker,
                'drag',
                function() {
                    //document.getElementById('lat').value = marker.position.lat();
                    //document.getElementById('lng').value = marker.position.lng();
                }
                );
        //})(commentMarker);

        google.maps.event.removeListener(listener1);
    }
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('popupComment').style.display='none';
}
```

Comment: ...I'm guessing you're getting no error in the console, correct?

Comment: something funky may be happening with your code before the line that is responsible for hiding the popup, because putting it on top of the function makes it disappear immediately, apparently ([see fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j3qo23s7/))

Comment: @webeno I forgot to mention above this is a Phonegap app I am using this for. I am just after running the app on an android phone and it worked fine so strangely it just seems to be affecting the app on iphone.

Answer (score -1):

Try to prevent form submit event.

```
<form onSubmit="return false">
```

Comment: inline `onsubmit` is about as bad as OP's inline `onclick`

Comment: No that didn't work, I have 'event.preventDefault();' at the buttom of my goCommenting() function so that should prevent the submit event anyway so I don't think that's the issue.

Comment: I don't think your `event.preventDefault()` should actually work this way, as you're not actually sending the event into the function (not 100% sure about that, but pretty sure, [see the example in the doc on event.preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)),  but that'd be an entirely different question, I think...